# Conditional operator issue

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I'm having some trouble with using the conditional operator to get a reference to an object. I have the a setup similar to this:

```
class D
{
    virtual void bla() = 0;
};

class D1 : public D
{
    void bla() {};
};

class D2 : public D
{
    void bla() {};
};

class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        this->d1 = new D1();
        this->d2 = new D2();
    }

    D1& getD1() {return *d1;};
    D2& getD2() {return *d2;}
private:
    D1 *d1;
    D2 *d2;
};

int main()
{    
    C c;    
    D& d = (rand() %2 == 0 ? c.getD1() : c.getD2());    
    return 0;    
}
```

When compiling, this gives me the following error:

```
WOpenTest.cpp: In function 'int
main()': WOpenTest.cpp:91: error: no
match for conditional 'operator?:' in
'((((unsigned int)rand()) & 1u) == 0u)
? c.C::getD1() : c.C::getD2()'
```

I understand this is illegal according to the C++ standard ([as seen in this blog post](http://big-bad-al.livejournal.com/95735.html)), but I don't know how to get my reference to `D` without using the conditional operator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cast to `D&` within both branches:

```
D& d = (rand() %2 == 0 ? static_cast<D&>(c.getD1()) : static_cast<D&>(c.getD2()));
```

Comment: You only need one of the casts here too, which makes the expression a little less verbose.

Comment: @Richard, ah good note. To me it looks easier if i apply the cast to both operands, but you are of course right, one cast suffices to make the compiler see the other one can be converted to `D&` implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Btw, you don't really need to use a conditional operator,

```
D* dptr; if(rand() %2 == 0) dptr = &c.getD1(); else dptr = &c.getD2();
D& d = *dptr;
```

would work too.

Comment: This looks to be a little wasteful. Is there a benifit to this approach verses the Ternary operator?

Comment: This is true, but I find the code looks clunky if you do this (using the reference looks cleaner).

Comment: Stephen, I was only providing an answer in response to OP's "but I don't know how to get my reference to D without using the ternary operator"

Comment: I suspect this falls into the category "personal preference": I do find it less clunky, especially since in this case a normal `(D&)`-cast is enough (casting to base class) so the ternary operator is perfectly readable and you don't have an extra variable which will be unused later on. I'm not sure the cast qualifies as RTTI use. Your answer, however, is perfectly valid, I do not understand why it was down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the return types of the functions to Base Class.

Comment: This would pepper the rest of the code using the two getters with dynamic casts, it's not really a solution